# Proguard returned with error code 1

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to create the signed apk of my app, but at the end of this procedure an error occurs "proguard returned with error code 1". I have checked couple of links
related with this issue where recommended to put some lines in proguard-project file but still couldn't fix it. following is the console picture of this issue.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you tried so far

Comment: first putted these lines in proguard-project but no difference

Comment: -dontwarn javax.jdo.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**

Comment: then these lines in proguard-android                                                             -keep class javax.ws.rs.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Gradle to build your app, what does your `proguardFiles` line look like for this build type?

It should look something like this: `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`, specifically the `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` is supposed to grab a file from the android sdk that should resolve this.